# Convert the code in twig from PHP

Tags: php, twig

I have tried to convert my templates from plain PHP to Twig code and I'm not sure from looking at the code how I would write the following examples out in Twig code. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My following PHP code.

```
<?php } if ($body_font != '' ) {
 $fontpre = $body_font;
 $font = str_replace("+", " ", $fontpre); ?>
body {font-family:<?php echo $font ?>;}
<?php } ?>
```

I have tried something following in twig.

```
{% if body_font != '' %}
{% set fontpre = 'body_font' %}
{% set font = fontpre|replace("+", " ") %}
 body {font-family:{{ font }}; }
{% endif %}
```

But, this doesn't work. Can you please help? What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`replace`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html) filter is different from PHP function [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). It accepts a mapping where keys are strings that should be replaced by values:

```
{% set font = fontpre|replace({"+": " "}) %}
```

Comment: you are right, and, another issue is. `$body_font` variable value is does not get. how to write `$fontpre = $body_font;` this code in proper way.

Comment: I have try this `{% set font = body_font|replace("+", " ") %}` and, Now it is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your twig code, you've initialized the variable `fontpre` with the string literal `body_font`. While in your php code, `$body_font` is a variable as well.

It is actually quite useless to set it again, you could use that variable directly in your php code (eg. `$font = str_replace("+", " ", $body_font); ?>`), but besides that; make sure that this particular variable is available in your twig code as well, or use a string literal referencing to a proper font family name. Although in that case you could skip the `replace` function altogether (as you can directly set it right.)